# tensorflow 1.13 how to use tf.searchsort safe?

Tags: python, tensorflow

With code

```
tf.searchsorted(input, input2)
```

I got **first error**

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Reshape cannot infer
>   the missing input size for an empty tensor unless all specified input
>   sizes are non-zero

It also reminded me in line 3459 of

> tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py
>
> searchsorted

got

```
sorted_sequence_2d = reshape(sorted_sequence, [-1, sequence_size])
```

But when tensor shape contain 0 dimension,  `input.shape=(0,)`, it will return an error. see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10609)

I want to check the tensor shape **before** using `tf.searchsorted`, and I know **the dimension is** `None`

So I use

```
if not tf.equal(input.shape[0], 0):
  tf.searchsorted(input, input2)
```

Then I got my **second error**, and I know that `tf.equal` will return bool tensor, which cannot be used like bool. But I don't know how to solve my first error.

> ValueError: Tried to convert 'x' to a tensor and failed. Error: Cannot
>   convert an unknown Dimension to a Tensor: ?

My question is how to use `tf.searchsort` safe if the first error trigered by `0` dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not explicitly stated, it is implied that [`tf.searchsorted`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/searchsorted) does not work with an empty sequence in the first parameter.

You can however use [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) to express something like "use searchsorted if it is not an empty sequence, otherwise return all zeros" (or whatever you prefer to return instead):

```
tf.cond(tf.not_equal(tf.size(input), 0),
        lambda: tf.searchsorted(input, input2),
        lambda: tf.zeros_like(input2, dtype=tf.int32))
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I need. I will first use tf.cond to check the cause of fiirst error. It's gona take a while cause the first error might happen  in 10k steps or 3k. It is random.

Comment: @TinaLiu Glad it helped. If you are trying to debug some error, you may consider using [`tf.print`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print), [assert operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/debugging) or even the [debugger](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/debugger) (although that is a bit more work to setup and use).

Comment: Hi, I confirm that the error is caused by zero size of the input. So it do worth a check before `searchsort`. Thanks again! Hey would you like to take a look at my another question? Give me some adivice maybe?[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58011264/transfer-python-code-to-tensorflow-while-the-autograph-dont-work)

Comment: @TinaLiu Thanks for the feedback. I had seen that question, but did not know how to answer at first sight (it's actually a difficult problem!). I'll see if I can think of something after another look.

Comment: I just thought it would be a better and accurate method when you need to upsample your labels. Anyway thanks!